# How should I use epoll to read and write from the same FD

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, asynchronous, epoll

### Environment

- Linux x64
- Ubuntu 16.4
- C++

### Use-case

- Async IO ( epoll )
- A socket is used for both reading and writing
- Read & Write operations and not in sync and are iteratively done on the socket

### Sample flow

1. Setup socket (*EPOLL_CTL_ADD*)
2. Start read (*EPOLL_CTL_MOD* + **EPOLLIN** | *EPOLLONESHOT*)
3. **While waiting for data to be read**

   - **[a]** Write some data (*EPOLL_CTL_MOD* + **EPOLLOUT** | *EPOLLONESHOT*)

### Problem description

- At #2 above a *EPOLLIN* read operation is registered
- At #3.a, a *EPOLLOUT* write completion is registered **before any data was read from the socket**
- Given the above, will the write completion operation @3.a cancel the pending read operation?

  - In other words, given the FD was initially called with (*EPOLL_CTL_MOD* + **EPOLLOUT**) that has no *EPOLLIN* set, will calling *EPOLL_CTL_MOD* + *EPOLLOUT* **erase** the previously registered *EPOLLIN* given data is not yet ready to be read ??

### A possible workaround for the above

- is to locally manage the req IO state by routing all read/write operations through the *epoll_wait* thread, hence, rather than calling *EPOLL_CTL_MOD* from an arbitrary thread, making sure it'll always be called from the same thread doing the *epoll_wait* where the FD IO state (*EPOLLOUT/EPOLLIN*) can be safely maintained.
- the problem w this workaround is that it req synchronizing all IO initiation through the *epoll_wait* thread, and that, result in an additional context switch that might adversely affect performance...

### That`s what I am trying to figure out:

Is there any way to sync the Read/Write IO operations on a common FD w/o the need of syncing through the *epoll_wait* thread? is there any way of directly calling *EPOLL_CTL_MOD* w/o resetting the previous state? is there any **thread safe way** of adding *EPOLLOUT* on an FD that already has *EPOLLIN* set ?

Comment: If you can read and write to two difeerent fds, you can read and write to the same fd with the exact same procedure. Just set the socket up once with EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT.

Comment: That is true, but then, I need to deal w situations where eg. there is pending read payload on the socket (EPOLLIN) and no buffer was provided where it is to be read into... and that req me to manage the FD state in a thread safe manner as it will be accessed by multiple threads... I would like to avoid this complexity if possible...

Calling eg. EPOLL_CTL_MOD + POLLEIN can be combined w/ providing a buffer, same goes for POLLEOUT... now, when reading payload is avail, EPOLL_CTL_MOD was called w POLLEIN | POLLEIN, BUT, the calling app is really interested only in writing data...

Comment: Interesting and I think related [EPOLL_CTL_DISABLE](https://lwn.net/Articles/520012/) although it focuses on deleting resources (in thread-safe manner)

Comment: You could also `dup()` the socket FD so that you'll have 2 distinct FDs, each with their own event mask.

Comment: yeah, certainly worth trying, I wonder if I'll get the epoll_wait notifications on the specific FD or on both of the copies... we'll see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOoo..., as @Hasturkun has suggested, using `dup` to filter EPOLLIN & EPOLLOUT events (in a thread safe manner) did the trick, however, to me, this looks more of a hack / workaround... I find it awkward that there is no more elegant solution... windows IOCompletion ports seems way more elegant to me...